# Compare two object in javascript based on true flag

Tags: javascript

I have one object like this

```
const values = [
{firstValue: "Michael", secondValue: "Malkovich"},
{firstValue: "John", secondValue: "Doe"},
{firstValue: "James", secondValue: "Doe"}
];
```

And another object like this

```
const incomingValues = {
Michael: true;
John: false;
James: true;
};
```

Based on this two object i need to make another that will filter values based on **true** or **false** and my final object must be like this

```
const filteredValues = [
    {firstValue: "Michael", secondValue: "Malkovich"},
    {firstValue: "James", secondValue: "Doe"}
];
```

you see there is no John anymore, because it has been false. I dont know how even to compare this two values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `filter` function from the Array object:

```
const filteredValues = values.filter(({ firstValue }) => incomingValues[firstValue]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
filteredValues = values.filter(item => {
    return incomingValues[item.firstValue] === true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Best Answer here

```
Object.keys(incomingValues).filter(y=>incomingValues[y]).map(i=>values.find(u=>i==u.firstValue))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
  as below -

```
const filteredValues = values.filter(e => incomingValues[e.firstValue]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ES6 arrow function for this. First you need to find the all the key which has true value. For this you can use below mentioned code.

```
const keys = Object.keys(incomingValues).filter(key => incomingValues[key]);
```

Now, your second step is to filter out the values array on the basic keys which you get earlier. For this you can use below mentioned code.

```
const result =  values.filter(value => keys2.indexOf(value.firstValue) >= 0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following

```
let filteredValues = values.filter(value => {
return incomingValues[value.firstValue];
});

let fileredTypeTwo = values.filter(function (value) {
return incomingValues[value.firstValue];
});
```